# What does "I spring the material" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Sator: You make your way there. I want Volkov on your team.
>
> Protagonist: No. I **spring** the material. You pay me off. Your wife does
> the exchange.

What does "spring" mean here?

Source: Christopher Nolan's movie [*Tenet* (2020)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenet_(film))

Comment: We need a bit more context here, please! There are various options. It could mean *spring for* (= *pay for*), it could mean *release, free*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Spring" is slang for 'steal'. It literally means to quickly move from one place to another. In your example then, someone is proposing a plan to steal some material which someone will then pay him for.

'Spring' can also be used to mean 'break out' or 'free' from jail, ie "*he was sprung from jail*".